# How do I measure whether the Facebook like box widget is effective on my site?

Tags: facebook, social-media, plugin, like

How can I tell if having the embedded Facebook iframe/html5 is any good at gathering a meaningful amount of page likes? (High enough to justify the real estate and extra load time it takes.)

I see plenty of big sites dropping it.  In fact I just went to ten or so random places and couldn't find any surviving example (not even buzzfeed!), not even of the tiny version of it.

In the insight section, I'm not sure where to look - some of the likes are attributed to 'your page', but does that include your Facebook page and the plugin on your site and, if yes, how many likes from which?

Comment: Is it possible to modify the script with any on click scripts to log the click, or can this be managed with an event tracker in analytics? How large is the Facebook javascript file? If it's topping 100kb it's probably too large. Can the javascript be cached so that the user doesn't have to reload it every day or on every page load? What does pagespeed insights say about the js file?

Answer (score 1):

If you not use javascript and div section you can track the clicks. About iframe i am not sure.

In video [**here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNG1gsrG6g0&t=157s) you can see it all setting up.

You can use something like this for the tracking:

```
onclick="ga('send','event','like','click','like','0');
```

And in Google analytics, you can set up.